# Defragment a file or folder? Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, defragment, virtual-drive

Is there a built-in way to defragment a folder? I am using VM Player so I would like my 3 GB disk image to be defragmented if possible.

My disk partition that the image lies in has 12 GB left and has roughly 90% of the disk used. I probably would not need a defrag but I would like to do it if it's possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do this with native commands but there are additional programs out there that allow you to selectively defrag individual files.

I've used programs like defraggler from the guys who brought you CCleaner.

Or a contig - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897428.aspx
Part of the Sysinternals Suite by Mark Russinovich.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have your OS and then your VM with it's OS image... instead of trying to defrag from your root/normal OS, why not try to do a defrag inside of your VM OS image - that is, run your VM and have it do a defrag.

Does that work for you?

Comment: @rlb.usa - A disk defragmentation from within the virtual machine will *not* do the same thing. The virtual image is a single file (or multiple) on the physical disk. Defragging from *within* the virtual machine will only rearrange the virtual files within the image. If that physical image file is scattered across the physical disk, defragging from the host OS will arrange the file's fragments so they are stored contiguously on the disk, increasing performance.